# Little diagram in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

I would like to draw the following diagram in my text:

[image: My little diagram]

How could I proceed?

Comment: The hardest part will be window in the background. ;-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: Drawing this background professionally would a great package... way better than [coffee stains](http://hanno-rein.de/archives/349) ;)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino What a beautiful package! Thank you for information!

Answer (score 6):

It's not a nice code but it may work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\overset{\underbrace{p \to F}}{\quad\left.\begin{matrix}F'\\ \uparrow\\ p'\end{matrix}\right\}}
\underbrace{F''\leftarrow p''}_{\quad\left.\begin{matrix}F'''\\ \uparrow\\ p'''\end{matrix}\right\}\displaystyle\mathrlap{\dots}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Basically I split the formula in two pieces: the left part is a vertical matrix on whose top the term with the underbrace is placed with `\overset`. The right part just uses `\underbrace` and puts the verical matrix under it. (One may have used `\underset` here.)

Answer (score 5):

**With tikz (decorations.pathreplacing library)**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

% define horizontal and vertical braces

\newcommand{\horbrace}[4][->]{
\node (#2)[right of=#3]{$#2$};
\draw[#1](#2)--(#3);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt},thick]
(#2.south east) -- (#3.south west) node(#4) [black,midway,below=5pt] {$#4$};}

\newcommand{\vertbrace}[3]{
\node (#2)[below of=#1]{$#2$};
\draw[->](#2)--(#1);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt},thick]
(#1.north east) -- (#2.south east) node(#3) [black,midway,right=5pt] {$#3$};}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,node distance=1.5cm]

\node (P){$P$};
\horbrace[<-]{F}{P}{F'}
\vertbrace{F'}{P'}{F''}
\horbrace{P''}{F''}{F'''}
\vertbrace{F'''}{P'''}{...}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in Tikz.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, positioning, calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[blue]
\node (A)                                          {$\bf{P} \rightarrow F$};
\node (C) [below=of A]                             {$\bf{P'}$};
\node (B) [below=of A, xshift=3mm, yshift=10mm]    {$\bf{F'}$};
\node (D) [xshift=15mm] at ($(A)!0.5!(C)$)         {$\bf{F''} \leftarrow P''$};
\node (E) [below=of D,yshift=9mm]                  {$\bf{F'''}$};
\node (F) [below=of E]                             {$\bf{P'''}$};
\node (G) [xshift=7mm] at ($(E)!0.5!(F)$)          {...};
\node (inv1) [right=of B, xshift=-12mm, yshift=0mm]{};
\node (inv2) [right=of C, xshift=-12mm, yshift=0mm]{};


\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]  (A.south west) -- (A.south east);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]  (D.south west) -- (D.south east);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace}]         (E.east)       -- (F.east);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace}]         (inv1.north)   |- (inv2.north);

\draw [shorten >=2mm, ->](C) -- (A);
\draw [->]               (F) -- (E);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possible output yet more organized.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, positioning, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[red]
%create nodes
\node (A)                                  {$\bf{P} \rightarrow F$};
\node (B) [below=of A,yshift=9mm]          {$\bf{F'}$};
\node (C) [below=of B]                     {$\bf{P'}$};
\node (D) [xshift=13mm] at ($(A)!0.5!(C)$) {$\bf{F''} \leftarrow P''$};
\node (E) [below=of D,yshift=9mm]          {$\bf{F'''}$};
\node (F) [below=of E]                     {$\bf{P'''}$};
\node (G) [xshift=7mm] at ($(E)!0.5!(F)$)  {...};

%connect nodes
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]  (A.south west) -- (A.south east);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]  (D.south west) -- (D.south east);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace}]         (E.east)       -- (F.east);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace}]         (B.east)       -- (C.east);
\draw [->] (C) -- (B);
\draw [->] (F) -- (E);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `$\bf{P} \rightarrow F$`?!  What are you trying to obtain?

Comment: @PrzemyslawScherwentke, what do you mean? This is shortcut instead of creating two nodes, therefore a single node with the text is enough.

Comment: Do you really want to make boldface both P and F? If yes, why `{P}`?

Comment: I'm not following you. Yes I want both boldface.

Comment: And, according to you, what `\bf` means?

Comment: `\bf` is alternative to `\textbf` I guess.

Comment: You ought not use `\bf` in LaTeX at all. It was deprecated 20+ years ago with the release of LaTeX 2e. It is not an alternative to `\textbf{}`. It is a deprecated (for LaTeX) font switch - similar, but not equivalent, to `\bfseries`. But this is not what you'd want in maths mode, anyway.

Comment: @cfr, hmmm, I had a discussion with my supervisor regarding this matter. He told me to stick with `\bf` and never use `\textbf`since it is an alternative. I like it because it is short.  I never knew it is obsolete.   Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your supervisor is wrong. Unless you are using TeX rather than LaTeX, it ought not be used. And it clearly isn't an alternative to `\textbf{}` since `\textbf{}` takes an argument and `\bf` does not. There's a question about this if you search.